# Editing an item from a list only pulls values from first entry in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters, edit

I haven't been able to find an answer on SO or through Google searching.

I have a list of submissions being displayed on the index page, made from the user's project show page. Url shows correct ID's and the data being entered is successful.

But, when I click on 'edit' for a particular submission, it jumps to the edit form with the correct url (ID's), but shows the first submission's values that were entered for the project. When you delete a submission it successfully deletes that submission. If you delete the first submission, the next submission's values will show and reflect on all other submissions, when edit is clicked. I'm at a loss here - appreciate the help!

Submission Index page:

```
<div class="row wrapper">
  <h2 class="color-blue"><%= @project.title %> Submissions</h2>
  <% if @project.submissions.present? %>
    <% @project.submissions.each do |submission| %>
      <div class="submission">
        <ul>
          <li class="title">
            <%= link_to submission.request_title, project_submission_path(@project, submission) %>
          </li>
          <li class="actions">
            <span class="edit">
              <%= link_to 'edit', edit_project_submission_path(@project, submission), class: 'color-orange' %> |
            </span>
            <span class="delete">
              <%= link_to 'delete', project_submission_path(@project, submission), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: 'color-red' %>
            </span> |
            <span class="send">
              <%= link_to 'send request', '#', class: 'color-atlantis' %>
            </span>
          </li>
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <br>
  <%= link_to "Back to #{@project.title} project", @project, class: 'color-clue' %>
</div>
```

Submissions controller:

```
class SubmissionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_project
  before_action :set_submission, only: [:destroy, :update, :edit, :create, :show]

  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @submission = @project.submissions.new
  end

  def edit

  end

  def create
    @submission = @project.submissions.new(submission_params)
    @submission.user = current_user

    if @submission.save
      redirect_to @project, notice: 'Music submission was successfully sent.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @submission.update(submission_params)
      redirect_to project_submissions_path(@project), notice: 'Music submission was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @submission.destroy
    redirect_to project_submissions_path(@project), notice: 'Music submission was successfully deleted.'
  end

  private

    def set_project
      @project = current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id])
    end

    def set_submission
      @submission = @project.submissions.find_by(params[:submission_id])
    end

    def submission_params
      params.require(:submission).permit(:request_title, :request_music, :notes, :terms)
    end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the `set_submission` method. It should be

```
def set_submission
  @submission = @project.submissions.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

or

```
def set_submission
  @submission = @project.submissions.find(params[:id])
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. The first suggestion returns the error `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty` and the second returns `Couldn't find Submission without an ID`

Comment: Yeah but the first error is another problem and it's not in the code we see, it should be in a form. And probably even the second one

Comment: My submissions form starts with `<%= form_for([project, submission]) do |f| %>` and I call the instance variables on the render `<%= render 'form', project: @project, submission: @submission %>`

Comment: Shouldn't be `<%= render 'form', locals: {project: @project, submission: @submission} %>`?

Comment: It was just `id`. I updated my answer. You should use on of the two lines in the answer anyway.

Comment: Ah that did it, thank you so much!! I also updated the method to your suggestion as well. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure Sir :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem in params attributes name. Check the server log when you click the edit button. Is it submission_id or just id?

Comment: Ah it's just ID `Parameters: {"project_id"=>"11", "id"=>"28"}`